# Can not connect to GPU device with OpenCL: invalid_value error

Tags: android, opencl

I want to set up a kernel for the Adreno 730 GPU in my Android tablet using OpenCL. I use `clGetDeviceIDs()` to connect to the GPU:

```
cl_device_id device_id; 
err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
```

During runtime, I receive the `CL_INVALID_VALUE` error, which occurs "*if num_entries is equal to zero and devices is not NULL or if both num_devices and devices are NULL.* Since non of the premises are given (`num_entries = 1`), I don't really understand how this error can occur.

When fetching a platform with `clGetPlatformIDs()` before getting a device ID, the app crashed immediately with the following log:

```
Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x726e6b1004 in tid 30364 (om.example.demo), pid 30364 (om.example.demo)
Cmdline: com.example.demo
pid: 30364, tid: 30364, name: om.example.demo  >>> com.example.demo <<<
#00 pc 0000000000001004  /data/app/~~bwptcAF2Mcxj1QrTS4VEAA==/com.example.demo-M6X_ed8wUlOuBtErB5lu1Q==/base.apk!ld-android.so (__loader_dlopen+4) (BuildId: daa6dd2d221674856cad38a0130d0b16)
#01 pc 00000000000010e0  /data/app/~~bwptcAF2Mcxj1QrTS4VEAA==/com.example.demo-M6X_ed8wUlOuBtErB5lu1Q==/base.apk!libdl_android.so (android_get_exported_namespace+12) (BuildId: a506d7cbefe663d77d99d39034bddf74)
#02 pc 0000000000001194  /data/app/~~bwptcAF2Mcxj1QrTS4VEAA==/com.example.demo-M6X_ed8wUlOuBtErB5lu1Q==/base.apk!libvndksupport.so (android_load_sphal_library+308) (BuildId: fa178c0474c2bbfb9380bc25fc0547ec)
#03 pc 0000000000021c70  /data/app/~~bwptcAF2Mcxj1QrTS4VEAA==/com.example.demo-M6X_ed8wUlOuBtErB5lu1Q==/base.apk!libOpenCL.so (clGetPlatformIDs+72) (BuildId: 4252b0a3fc7297cc93dfa7a31c208d1f)
#04 pc 0000000000005d30  /data/app/~~bwptcAF2Mcxj1QrTS4VEAA==/com.example.demo-M6X_ed8wUlOuBtErB5lu1Q==/base.apk!libdemo.so (Java_com_example_demo_MainActivity_getInt+32) (BuildId: a0b5246c34b8e042c29bfe224a864d949ab56d04)
#07 pc 0000000000000eac  /data/app/~~bwptcAF2Mcxj1QrTS4VEAA==/com.example.demo-M6X_ed8wUlOuBtErB5lu1Q==/base.apk (com.example.demo.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0+48)
#09 pc 0000000000000e1c  /data/app/~~bwptcAF2Mcxj1QrTS4VEAA==/com.example.demo-M6X_ed8wUlOuBtErB5lu1Q==/base.apk (com.example.demo.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$KC6AjQoJlmGj4vROYZUNl9WDJyU+0)
#11 pc 0000000000000dd4  /data/app/~~bwptcAF2Mcxj1QrTS4VEAA==/com.example.demo-M6X_ed8wUlOuBtErB5lu1Q==/base.apk (com.example.demo.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick+4)
#17 pc 00000000002e7432  /data/app/~~bwptcAF2Mcxj1QrTS4VEAA==/com.example.demo-M6X_ed8wUlOuBtErB5lu1Q==/base.apk (com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick+22)
```

The problem seems to be in `ld-android.so`. I got the library directly from `/system/lib64/`.

Comment: Does clinfo run successfully and detect you GPU?

Comment: @SimonGoater I have not rooted my device yet. The last Logcat-entry is from libc.so: `Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x726e76a004 in tid 29952`.

Comment: @SimonGoater OpenCL does not even find the CPU: `err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 0, NULL, &num_devices);`will yield `0`for the`num_devices` property.

Comment: I've seen a few questions on here about how to install OpenCL properly on Android. I've never tried to do it myself though so I don't think I'm going to be much help. I do know however, that OpenCL usually requires special drivers for CPUs and GPUs. Maybe you can research what drivers are required and check you have them installed.

Comment: @SimonGoater the drive don't seem to be a problem. `ld-android.so` seems to have a problem. When I try to query a platform before getting the device, the app crashes immediately and yield the log which I added to the post above.